# Cookie file for Google Chrome / unix

Tags: cookies, google-chrome

Where does Chrome store its cookie file on a unix system?

Answer (score 23):

~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies

Comment: And if you have chromium, it will be:

    ~/.config/chromium/Default/Cookies

Answer (score 11):

fwiw, that file is a SqLite database...

```
$ file ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies 
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies: SQLite 3.x database

$ sqlite -version
2.8.17
```

...good luck...

Answer (score 6):

You can use Sqlite Browser with graphic interface.

```
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

Open the cookie file with Sqlite Browser. You may find the cookie file belongs to a hidden folder so hard to select it by mouse, just provide the full path of your cookie file when open:

```
/home/your_name/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies
```

Once you open Sqlite Browser and open the database file you will see two tables: (1) cookies and (2) meta;

You can execute a SQL command, e.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM cookies WHERE host_key = ".example.com";
```